# How to wait for transition animation to finish when calling Navigation.PushAsync in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation

We're developing an app using xamarin.forms and using the MVVM pattern. We're using the built in navigation system to push and pop pages. Now we're running into an issue when navigating pages using commands.

Say we have a view with a button that navigates to another page. This navigation is done by binding a viewmodel command to the button. The command has a canExecute check, which checks the "IsBusy" property, to prevent the button from being clicked twice, and initiating two page navigations.

Example code:

view:

```
<Button Command={Binding NavigateCommand} />
```

viewmodel (i've left out the notifypropertychanged and ChangeCanExecute calls, which do exist):

```
Public bool IsBusy {get => _isBusy set => {_isBusy = value;}}
Public ICommand NavigateCommand = New Command(Navigate, () => !IsBusy);

async private Task Navigate()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Now you would say that this works, which is kind of does. However, we've implemented custom transition animations in Android that slides the new page into view from the right, and removes the old one by sliding it out of view to the left. The problem is, that the PushAsync method is awaited, but it completes as soon as the page is loaded, but before the animation to move it into view has completed. So during the transition animation, the command can execute again, and it is still possible to execute the command twice.

TLDR:
Is there any way to wait for page transition animations to finish when using PushAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right,

I got some suggestions via other channels about using animation listeners. I've been fiddling a bit but I was unable to use them to solve the issue. I've taken a look in the xamarin forms source code, and it seems that internally, the navigationpagerenderer also doesn't use an event, but uses a constant (const int TransitionDuration = 220;) to wait for the transition to finish. However, we use a longer animation, that causes the issue. In the master branch of xamarin.forms, the TransitionDuration variable has become virtual, so we can override once they release a version with this code included.

This still seems like a bit wonky solution to me. It would be better to have some way of having an event when the transition finishes, but it seems the even the people writing xamarin.forms haven't been able to accomplish this.

If anyone has a better suggestion I would really like to hear it

Comment: If you know the transition time, can you create a timer in the onappearing of the page, that invokes an event as soon as time runs out (e.g. transition duration is over)? If you know the transition time you might be able to fix this by finding out when it really starts to transition.

Comment: Thats sort of what I'm doing as a workaround now. But that is still a bit of a dodgy solution. I would really like to be able to wait until the transition has actually finished, instead of waiting for an amount of time, and assuming the transition is finished after that time.